# Chebyshev formula question

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm stuck with this problem, I want to show that if $f$ is an integrable function then $$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}t\mu\{x\in \mathbb{R}^d:|f(x)|>t\}=0.$$ I have the feeling that I should use the Chebyshev's inequality, but I don't know how to use it in this case. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

For $t\geq0$:

$$0\leq t\mu\left\{ f>t\right\} =\int_{f>t}td\mu\leq\int_{f>t}\left|f\left(t\right)\right|d\mu$$

So it remains to be shown that: $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{f>t}\left|f\left(t\right)\right|d\mu=0$$

For this you can use the fact that $f$ is integrable wrt $\mu$.